# Look up most viewed posts for a tag

Tags: discussion, support, views, question-lists

For any particular tag we have the ability to lookup questions with most votes.

There is "frequent" tab, which shows up questions with most links. I am assuming these are posts that are most referenced by other Stack Overflow posts.

But isn't there a way to look up questions by most views? I am just wondering if anyone came across the need to sort questions by their views counter.

Comment: You could use a SEDE query, but the results are only updated on sundays.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a SEDE query, [Most viewed questions in tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/341524/most-viewed-questions-in-tag), that fetches questions sorted by views. As mentioned in the comments, SEDE is only updated once a week, but those results shouldn't change drastically in that time, at least for the most popular tags.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the **real-time** [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) feature?

```
[tag] views:0
```

Play the number! Try different values for `views`.
Increase if you get many results, decrease if you get no results.